# VBA Powerpoint slide table data to combobox item

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This is my first question, so sorry for terminology. 
I'm beginner in VBA, so I'm stopped in few questions.

I'm working in Powerpoint. I have combobox and I want to add items from table (it could be as table, or Excel spreadSheet) which is on previous slide.

I found one example for Excel (I don't know if will work in PPT):

```
Sub Loadbox()
    row_review = 1
    Dim TheSheet As ?????
    Set TheSheet = ?????
    Do
    DoEvents
    row_review = row_review + 1
    item_in_review = TheSheet.Range("A" & row_review)
        If Len(item_inreview) > 0 Then ComboBox1.AddItem (item_in_review)

    Loop Until item_in_review = ""
End Sub
```

But I couldn't understand how to define table from witch I get data for item.

Maybe there is better way how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To read the contents of the first cells of a row in a PowerPoint table this is the starting point.

```
Dim tbl As Table 
Dim i As Long

Set tbl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).Table
For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
    Debug.Print tbl.Cell(i, 1).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
Next
```